# Массивы со строкой в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Если массив arr содержит строку, то будут ли различаться значения, которые вернут функции sizeof() и strlen()?​

Comment: Вопрос точно по питону? И что мешает проверить самостоятельно?

Comment: Плоховато знаю массив в данном языке, жабу знаю,но не змея

Comment: Так а задача какая?

Comment: Это просто вопрос

Comment: А при чем тут массив? И к чему конкретно приминяем sizeof?

Comment: Это просто вопрос! Не более. Надо так.

Comment: Ну если это просто вопрос, то он бессмысленный и бесполезный.

Comment: -_- ладно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sys.getsizeof() возвращает сколько занимает места объект в памяти, в то время как len() возвращает длинну строки. Т.к. в python строка это тоже объект то она даже не имея символов занимает место в памяти. Поэтому возвращаемый результат будет обязательно отличаться. Еще sys.sizeof() зависит от символов которые содержит строка, например русские символы будут занимать больше памяти из-за кодировки.
Например:

```
>>> getsizeof('')
25
>>> getsizeof('test')
29
>>> getsizeof('тест')
46
```

Comment: Что-то у вас размеры маленькие. 32-битный питон, наверное? )

Comment: @CrazyElf давайте не будем стыдить членов сообщества тем, что у них питон маленький

Comment: Главное то как ты его используешь